# Swift table view with a cell that is transparent and shows background image

Tags: swift, tableview, transparency, uitableview

I have tried to do so:

- added an orange view behind a table view.
- for a certain cell hide with alpha = 0 all her elements
- tried to make the cell transparent so that it shows the orange view behind the table view while it scrolls:

  ```
  cell2.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
  cell2.backgroundView = nil
  cell2.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
  ```
- tried to make the table view transparent so that it allows the orange view behind to be showed

  ```
  tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
  tableView.opaque = false
  tableView.backgroundView = nil
  ```

However I can not see the orange view behind the table view when I scroll and get to my cell, it just shows a grey cell.

Can somebody give me any hint to what else I should do?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `viewDidLoad()`, add the code immediately below to set the tableView's background color.

```
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, use something similar to the code below to set a given cell's backgroundColor to be transparent, where the value *2* is the row of the cell you'd like to change.

```
switch indexPath.row {
case 2:
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
default:
    print("NOT Clear")
}
```